# My installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS always gets very slow after a few days, with lots of disk read/write. Any suggestions?

Tags: performance

I have an HP PC I use for development with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

After a few days it gets really, really sluggish.  When you click in a window it takes 5-10 seconds for that window to get focus.  In the meantime, it goes through a cycle of greying out and in (indicating non-responsiveness).  I can also hear the hard drive scrambling away while this happens.  It is even hard to reboot because it takes forever to close windows, and it slowly gets to saying 'application  is not responding.  Force quit?'.

A reboot always fixes it, but in a few days it is back to thrashing.

Any advice how to fix this?  It's not like I am taxing the system.  usually, at worst, I have two web browsers, a few terminals doing nothing, and one instance of Emacs open.

Comment: Could you have a memory bottleneck and make the system swap? When the system is slow, do `free` and add the result to your question.

Comment: Use `ps -ef` to see if you're leaving processes lying around. `top` is good, too. Of course read `man ps;man top`

Comment: When using top, one of the biggest users is Chrome; one of the processes use 12% of CPU ans 14% of memory.  There are a bunch of smaller Chrome processes as well - I assume the big one is the main process, and others are per-tab or some such?

Comment: 'free', by the way, givesas follows....mem: 8061996(total), 6228792(used), 471404(free), 593436(shared), 1361800(buff/cache), 846668(available).  The next line gives....Swap: 8275964(totla), 3041176(used), 5234788(free).

Comment: In the last 12 hours it went into a very, very slow state.  'free' shows the mem: free has dropped a little, to 471404.  The big change is that 'top' has two processes now called 'web content' that together are about 40% of CPU and 30% of memory.